# How to flatten Object by using GroupBy and Select

Tags: c#

I have a collection of ObjectA

```
 class ObjectA{
   public  DateTime date {get; set;}
   public  int  Code  {get; set;}
   public  decimal Value {get; set;}
    }


List<ObjectA> objectAList = GetObjectAList();
```

There are 3 different Codes.

```
 class ObjectB{
   public DateTime Date {get;set;}
   public decimal Code1 {get;set;}
   public decimal Code2 {get;set;}
   public decimal Code3 {get;set;}
    }
```

I would like to flatten the list of object A's as list of ObjectB's

I tried to do this by using GroupBy with no success:

```
objectAList .GroupBy (l => l.Code).Select (l => new {
       Code1 = l.Where (x => x.Code== 1).Select (x => x.Value ),
       Code2 = l.Where (x => x.Code== 2).Select (x => x.Value ),
       Code3 = l.Where (x => x.Code== 3).Select (x => x.Value )
    });
```

But Not sure how to get the Date from this query and attach it in the ObjectA?

Comment: Which date do you choose?  Which one takes precedence?

Comment: Shouldn't you group by the `Date` then select the code values somehow?

Comment: I should definitely group by date yes. But how. I cannot group twice

Comment: Some example data and expected results would be helpful. It seems you misunderstand `GroupBy`. `GroupBy(l => l.Code)` results in an enumeration of enumeration of `ObjectA` that have the _same_ `Code`, so the `Where`s don't really make sense anymore...

Comment: Are the `Code`s unique per `Date`?

Comment: yes for each month. so for each month each code has only single entry. Somehow instead of running to pull the values for each month I would like to get all data for a year then flatten the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to create a collection of instances of `ObjectB` that has instances of `ObjectB` for each `Date`, containing the `Value` of the three `CodeX` properties for this `Date` (assuming there is **only one** `Code1`, `Code2` and `Code3` per `Date`).

So this should do what you want:

```
var objectBList = objectAList.GroupBy(a => a.Date)
          .Select(group => new ObjectB{
               Date = group.Key,
               Code1 = group.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Code == 1)?.Value ?? 0,
               Code2 = group.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Code == 2)?.Value ?? 0,
               Code3 = group.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Code == 3)?.Value ?? 0})
          .ToList();
```

This groups the `ObjectA`s by their `Date` (which will be the `Date` of the created `ObjectB`) and sets the `CodeX` according to the `Value`s of the `ObjectA`s with the corresponding code.

So the result (`objectBList`) is a list containing an `ObjectB` for each `Date` that contains the `Value`s of the three rows for that `Date`.

---

If you have more than one `CodeX` per `Date` you might want to aggregate those `Value`s instead. [juharr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38103390/5528593) provided an example for that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want one `ObjectB` for each unique `Date` in your list, so you should group by that instead

```
objectAList .GroupBy (l => l.Date)
            .Select (l => new ObjectB 
            {
                Date = l.Key.Date,
                Code1 = l.Where(x => x.Code == 1).Sum(x => x.Value),
                Code2 = l.Where(x => x.Code == 2).Sum(x => x.Value),
                Code3 = l.Where(x => x.Code == 3).Sum(x => x.Value)
            });
```

I'm summing all the values for each given code, but you can aggregate the values how you like.

Comment: Why do I need to use Sum? I do not want to aggregate the values. I just would like to flatten each data. Basically from rows to columns

Comment: @akd In that case you could just use `FirstOrDefault` if you know there is one Code per Date.